# Use case diagrams like yuml.me

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

looking for windows software who can draw a Use Case diagram like yuml.me

anyone recognize this font

http://yuml.me/490176a.jpg

Comment: That is *so* not a programming question …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, we used Ruffscript :)

http://hiran.in/blog/rufscript-font

Comment: thanks for ur answer ..... this is what im searching